# Is there any difference between the exression "by car" and "in a car"?

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

Is there any difference between "by car" and "in a car"? For example:

> I usually come to work **by car**/**in a car**.

Comment: **By car** is idiomatic; **in a car** is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first describes the conveyance, that is, the primary means by which you come. The second describes something that happens coincidentally. For example, if you were sitting in a car being carried by a flatbed truck, you would be going to work **by** truck, **in** a car.

Following this construction one could go to work **by** car **in** ones pajamas, or **in** a Scottish kilt decorated with rutabagas, or **in** a state of joyful mirth.

The difference is fairly nuanced. I would say that in practice both versions are perfectly understandable.